Using a texture for x/y inputs of Translate Node in Compositor, possible?
is there any way to use a textures value as the input for the x/y offset of a translate node in the compositor? It just won't work. I'd like to create some kind of rgb artifacts and maybe some strange distortions.

You should use the displace node instead.


indeed, that works. thank you. sorry i am to low of a member to upvote ;)
